# Hide region when block menu is empty

Tags: 8, blocks, theming

I got the 2nd level main menu in a block in the sidebar, drupal 8 correctly hides the menu (and the block) when the user browses a page that is not in this menu, but the theme continues to show the empty region. 
The condition {% if page.region %} is true. 
is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: First you should check whats inside page.region with `{{ kint(page.region) }}` (devel kint module enabled). It seems not to be empty.

Answer (score 4):

It is better to use construction

```
{% if page.region|render|striptags|trim|length > 0 %} ... {% endif %}
```

So you can check if there is some content or not.

Comment: Note: This will not work properly if a region contains only HTML tags, such as Search Facets that are completely made up of <select> options.  The striptags call will remove everything from these regions, making them appear to be empty and preventing your facets from showing.

Answer (score 2):

I you use [menu_block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module, [this patch](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stef-van-looveren/drupal-8-patches/master/menu_block-8.x-1.5-empty-region.patch) will fix the problem of a region showing up even when there are no subitems for a menu. Only tested on menu block version 8.x-1.5.

Comment: your patch work nice vs the 8.x-1.5. Have you open an issue on the module page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{% if page.region|render|striptags %}` to make sure the regions actually has content. See also the discussion here: [[meta] Themes improperly check renderable arrays when determining visibility](https://www.drupal.org/node/953034).

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way to reduce the number of renders.

```
{% set render_sidebar_first = page.sidebar_first|render %}
{% if render_sidebar_first and render_sidebar_first|striptags|trim|length > 0 %}
  {% block sidebar_first %}
    <aside class="{{ sidebar_class }}" role="complementary">
        {{ render_sidebar_first }}
    </aside>
  {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```